# Good approach to determine quality of a human posture with TensorFlow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

i try to determine the quality of a person's sitting posture. (e.g. sitting upright = good / sitting crouched = bad) with a webcam.

**First try:**

- Image aquisition (with OpenCV python bindings)
- Create a dataset with labeled images into good/bad
- Feature detection (FAST)
- Train a neuronal net on the dataset with that features(ANN_MLP)

The result was ok with a few restrictions:

- not invariant to webcam movements, displacement, other persons, objects etc.
- iam not sure if FAST features will fit
- im pretty new to machine learning and want to try more sophisticated approaches with TensorFlow:

**Second try:**

I tried human pose detection via Tensorflow [PoseNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet)
And got a mini example working which can determine probabilities of human bodypart positions. So now the challenge would be to detect the quality of a person's sitting posture out of the output of PoseNet.

What is a good way to proceed:

1. train a second TF model which gets probabilities of human bodypart
   positions as input and outputs good/bad posture? (so PoseNet is used as fancy feature detector)
2. rework the PoseNet model to fit my output needs  and retrain it?
3. transfer learning from PoseNet (i just read about it but have no clue how or if its even applicable here)?
4. or maybe a complete different approach?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think this is an impossible question to answer seriously here, as it requires a whole thesis worth of explanation and thought. Please see [ask]. My advice, start trying all those methods, ask questions as they arise naturally from your code

Comment: you can forward the output form PoseNet or Openpose to https://github.com/ArashHosseini/3d-pose-baseline, it will give you more than the screenspace skeleton

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try out the different methods. Thanks also for pointing to OpenPose / pose-baseline.